# Does the .swz file have to be in the same directory as your project .swf?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash

I've heard swz needs to be in the same directory as the swf project file in order to run the library (or use as a rsl.) Is this true? Or can it be any where on the server and you just point your project towards it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope they can be anywhere as long as you specify the urls in your build configuration.